# Vertically align content within CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a CSS Grid below and I would like the content(letters for now) to be vertically aligned within the cells. What's the best way to accomplish this? `vertical-align:middle` on the cells doesn't seem to do anything, `align-items:center;` on the grid container worked, but then the heights were all different.

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: [col] 100px [col] 100px [col] 100px;
  grid-template-rows: [row] auto [row] auto [row] ;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
 }

 .box {
  background-color:#444;
  color:#fff;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:150%;
 }

 .a {
  grid-column: col / span 2;
  grid-row: row 1 / 3;
 }
 .b {
  grid-column: col 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: row ;
 }
 .c {
  grid-column: col 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: row 2 ;
 }
 .d {
  grid-column: col / span 1;
  grid-row: row 3;
 }

 .e {
  grid-column: col 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: row 3;
 }

.f {
  grid-column: col 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: row 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want them vertically centered you can add `display:flex;` and `align-items: center;` to the box class:

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: [col] 100px [col] 100px [col] 100px;
  grid-template-rows: [row] auto [row] auto [row];
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.a {
  grid-column: col / span 2;
  grid-row: row 1 / 3;
}

.b {
  grid-column: col 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: row;
}

.c {
  grid-column: col 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: row 2;
}

.d {
  grid-column: col / span 1;
  grid-row: row 3;
}

.e {
  grid-column: col 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: row 3;
}

.f {
  grid-column: col 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: row 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working. But there are side effects if there is not only text in cells. E.g. links, other elements. It's better to wrap flex content in divs. I.e: <div class="box a"><div>A</div></div> See https://dev.to/afif/never-make-your-text-container-a-flexbox-container-m9p